# Variables behave unexpectedly in while loop

Tags: bash, variable

This is a re-post of the [same question in Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/how-to-edit-the-headers-of-multiple-fasta-files-from-multiple-folders-recursiv). The given answer didn't work for me, and I thought I'd ask here.

My directories are organized as follows: one main directory, in which I have multiple project directories (start with 'mgp'). Inside each project directory, there are multiple metagenome directories (start with 'mgm' and end with '.3'). Inside each metagenome directory, there is always a single text .fna (fasta) file. Fasta files are defined by the following structure:

```
>Header1
Sequence1
```

```
>Header2
Sequence2
```

What I want is a loop that would go through all these fasta files, and add to the headers codes corresponding to project and metagenome directory. For example, if the fasta file in project directory mgp83581, metagenome subdirectory mgm4729322.3 had the following headers...

```
>seq1
>seq2
```

...then I would want to change it to:

```
>83581_322_seq1
>83581_322_seq2
```

Basically, I want to add the number code associated with the project, and the last three digits of the 7-digit code associated with the metagenome (apart from the '.3' part of the file name). That part of the code is okay. I know it works on one file at a time.

This is the full code I have right now. It does not work. (it only works for one of my two test files)

```
ls mgp*/mgm*.3/*.fna |  while read line ; do
        header=$(sed -r "s/^mgp([0-9]*)\/mgm[0-9]{4}([0-9]{1,})\.3\/(mgm.*\.fna)/\1_\2/") #this is where I get the code I want from the path
        sed -i.bak "s/^>/>${header}_/" $line  #this is where I add said code to my file
done
```

Individually, parts of the code 'seem' to work. If I write

```
ls mgp*/mgm*.3/*.fna | while read line ; do
        echo $line
done
```

...then I am able to recover the paths for both my test files of interest. If I write:

```
ls mgp*/mgm*.3/*.fna | while read line ; do
    echo $line
    header=$(sed -r "s/^mgp([0-9]*)\/mgm[0-9]{4}([0-9]{1,})\.3\/(mgm.*\.fna)/\1_\2/")
    echo $header
done
```

...then I get something rather weird. I get:

```
path for file#1
header for file #2
```

Whereas, I'd expect to get:

```
path for file#1
header for file#1
path for file#2
header for file#2
```

I've looked at previous questions/answers that discussed how the behaviour of variables in a while loop can be a bit strange, but I'm afraid I don't understand quite enough to make things work.

Comment: Rhetorical question: What are you applying the `sed` command to in your last loop?

Comment: Do you _really_ have to use `bash`? Try this: `for f in mgp*/mgm*.3/*.fna; do (IFS='./'; set -- $f; sed "s|^> *\(seq.*\)|>${1#mgp}_${2#${2%???}}_\1|" "$f"); done` (add the the `-i` switch to `sed` if everything's OK).

Answer (score 4):

Your main issue is that you are running `sed` without giving it any input, which means that it would read its standard input stream which is inherited from the encompassing loop, which contains the names of the files that you pass from `ls` (all in the first iteration of the loop). An additional issue is that you are using `ls` to list your files (it's easier and safer to just loop over the filenames than to correctly read the output of `ls`). Also, the code is a bit difficult to read, given the somewhat involved regular expression that you use.

---

To loop over your files, use

```bash
for pathname in mgp*/mgm*.3/*.fna; do
   # ... use "$pathname" here ...
done
```

To get the three digit genome code from the subdirectory name, given the pathname of a fasta file in `$pathname`:

```bash
genome=${pathname%.3/*.fna}     # trim off tail
genome=${genome#mgp*/mgm????}   # trim off head
```

This will give you e.g. `322` in `$genome` from `mgp83581/mgm4729322.3/blah.fna` in `$pathname`.

In the same manner, to get the project number:

```bash
project=${pathname%/mgm*.3/*.fna}   # trim off tail
project=${project#mgp}              # trim off head
```

Now `$project` would be `83581`, and `$genome` is `322`.

To insert these after each `>` at the start of the line in each fasta file:

```bash
for pathname in mgp*/mgm*.3/*.fna; do
    genome=${pathname%.3/*.fna}     # trim off tail
    genome=${genome#mgp*/mgm????}   # trim off head

    project=${pathname%/mgm*.3/*.fna}   # trim off tail
    project=${project#mgp}              # trim off head

    sed -i .old "s/^>/>${project}_${genome}_/" "$pathname"
done
```

This would additionally back up the old files with a `.old` suffix.

Note: Test this on a *copy* of your own data.  I have no fasta files available and I haven't tested the final loop.

Comment: The `sed` won't _block_ the loop, it'll just read all the data from the pipe, which explains why the loop only runs once.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah, yes of course! I forgot about the loop having input. Thanks for thinking.